line break on text created by createElementNS
I feel like I have a very dumb question: I create a text with the following command:
text = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text")
text.textContent = "some very long text"

How can I make the string printed span over many lines? The common '\n' doesn't work. And I found some solutions for html text using the <br/> command, but I don't know to convert the text to html. I also tried
text.innerHTML = "some text" + <br/> + "some more text"

but this didn't work.

There's likely an error in your console with your text.innerHTML attempt because you are treating <br/> like a variable, which it isn't. It's part of the html, so include it in the string: text.innerHTML = "some text<br/>some more text"

This I tried as well, but the <br/> just gets ignored. Do you know why?

See this question

This question is similar to: How to linebreak an svg text within javascript?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

SVG text elements don't support line breaks or HTML tags directly. Instead, you must manually break the text into separate  elements. Each  can be positioned separately to simulate line breaks. Here's an example:
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");
const text = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 
"text");
text.setAttribute("x", "10");
text.setAttribute("y", "20");
text.setAttribute("font-size", "16");

const lines = ["some very long text", "that spans over", "multiple lines"];

lines.forEach((line, index) => {
    const tspan = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 
    "tspan");
    tspan.setAttribute("x", "10");
    tspan.setAttribute("dy", "1.2em");
    tspan.textContent = line;
    text.appendChild(tspan);
 });

 svg.appendChild(text);

